# BigQuery Command Line Tool: get error details

Tags: google-bigquery

one of my jobs keeps failing and when I looked into why (by requesting job details) I get the following output:

```
status": {
"errorResult": {
  "location": "gs://sf_auto/Datastore Mapper modules.models.userData/15716706166748C8426AD/output-46",
  "message": "JSON table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1.",
  "reason": "invalid"
},
"errors": [
  {
    "location": "gs://sf_auto/Datastore Mapper modules.models.userData/15716706166748C8426AD/output-46",
    "message": "JSON table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1.",
    "reason": "invalid"
  }
],
"state": "DONE"
```

Problem is, it doesn't help at all, and I need more details. Is there anyway to understand which column or attribute caused the failings? Is there any way to get more information?

**Edit Additional Details**

- We're running a map reduce job on appengine to transfer our datastore from appengine to BigQuery
- The files are stored on Google Cloud Store
- It's creating a brand new table instead of adding to an existing one

**Update #2**
I played around with the query trying lots of things as well as adjusting the scheme and i've narrowed down the problem to the uuid. For some reason this type of data messes everything up:

"uuid": "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"

The schema defines it as a String

Comment: Oh and since it took me FOREVER to figure it out, here's a tip for others... if you want to get a list of jobs use: bq ls -j -a . If you want to see job details use: bq --format=prettyjson show -j <job_id>

Comment: can you post details about the job you are running? is it a insertion job? a table creation one?

Comment: Hey Will just updated it to include additional details, let me know if more information would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after loads of debugging I found the error... in the JSON Newline file we had two attributes that were similar:

uuid: "XXX..."
uuId: "XXX..."

This has been there for a while so I think some change within bigquery started to require that keys be unique regardless of capitalization. Will test so more and confirm!

Comment: confirmed, there is some kind of new uniqueness check for column names that dis-regards capitalization -- not sure if it's a bug or a feature

Answer (score 0):

A recent change made loads of JSON data case insensitive in field names similar to be consistent with how SQL queries treat field names. I have opened a work item to track the improvement of error message for this case.